# How to fill this huge space in MS Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word

How to fill this huge space in **MS Word 2007**?

[image: wasted space]

I am struggling hard to find out how to fill this huge space which get wasted in MS Word 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to draft or web layout :) You're looking at the print layout. If your goal is just to write HTML, you won't see this space when it's exported. If you do intend to print, the space is actually taken up by the header, as well as "space before" on your header 1 style (I assume you're using styles).

For the header, as @hanjo mentions, just reduce your margins. Also check the Header 1 style, as that frequently has extra space before, depending on your template (Paragraph formatting, Indents and Spacing, Space Before - 12 points is the default, which is a lot of white space).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you would like to do with it.

1. If you would like to use the space for the content on your document, you need to make the margins smaller. On the ribbon "Page Layout" there is a drop down "Margins" which you can use to reduce the margin to your preference.
2. If you would like to use it for meta-information, you can insert headers or footers by either double-clicking in the void there or by selecting the "Header" or "Footer" option on the ribbon "Insert", e.g. to insert a disclaimer, a document title, the date, the page number, etc.